# Extending Googles HelloAnalytics Python script to pull out the data in a csv

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

Looking for help trying to place the output of this HelloAnalytics Python example into a data frame so that I can export it to CSV in a tabular format.

Here's the function that calls the output and here's the [full code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py) from Google:

```
def main():
    analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
    response = get_report(analytics)
    print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main().
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you get in response? What did you try to do with this? If you have `pandas.DataFrame` then it has `df.to_csv(...)`

Comment: you could modify `print_response` and add elements to lists instead of printing - and then you can write it with stadnard module `csv`